# Регулярное выражение для ФИО

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, asp.net-mvc

Нужно регулярное выражение где в имени первая буква должна быть большой и другие большие буквы нужно запретить, за исключением случая когда имя пишется через дефис, тогда разрешается большая буква первая и которая идет сразу после дефиса, остальные нельзя. 
Например

Дмитрий - ОК

ДмИтрий - Ошибка

Дмитрий-Иосиф - ОК

ДмИтрий-Иосиф - Ошибка

Дмитрий-иосиф - Ошибка

Получилась регулярка у меня, только допускающая одну большую вначале, но через дефис имя уже воспринимает неправильно т.к. после дефиса идет еще одна большая.

Мое выражение

`@"^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё\-]+\s([А-ЯЁ][а-яё\-]+)(\.|\s)\s*([А-ЯЁ][а-яё\-\.]+)$"`

В нем используется шаблон Ф И О

Comment: В регулярке вы приравняли дефис к маленьким буквам, а хотите использовать его как разделитель

Comment: А как насчёт _Мустафа-заде_ или там _фон Гуттенберг_?

Comment: Есть ещё люди с двойной фамилией и люди без отчества.

Comment: Да это бывает конечно, но предусматривается, что самое страшное что будет это ФИО содержащее дефис

Comment: может быть двойное имя или фамилия или отчество без дефиза. А вобще в крупных гос бд делают все большими буквами(думаю понятно почему). И вам советую нечто подобное вместо регулярок(часть людей прост не сможет зарегистрироваться или что там у вас).

Comment: @FORTRAN согласен с вами, но таково ТЗ, и более того, я совершенно уверен, что в скором времени они это все отменят

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

```
^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:-\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)?$
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BLl%7D*%28%3F%3A-%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BLl%7D*%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%0D%0A%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%0D%0A%0D%0A%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%98%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%0D%0A%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%98%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%0D%0A%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84&o=m).

Подробности:

- `^`  - начало строки
- `\p{Lu}` - заглавная буква
- `\p{Ll}*` - 0 и более строчных букв
- `(?:-\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)?` - необязательная последовательность следующих шаблонов:

  - `-` - дефис
  - `\p{Lu}` - заглавная буква
  - `\p{Ll}*` - 0 и более строчных букв
- `$` - конец строки.

Если нужна поддержка *только* русских букв, замените

```
\p{Lu} --> [А-ЯЁ]
\p{Ll} --> [а-яё]
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать чтобы эта же регулярка соответствовала шаблону ФИО, то есть Фамилия пробел Имя пробел Отчество ?

Comment: `^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:-\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)? \p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:-\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)? \p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:-\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)?$` должна сработать. Пробелы можно заменить `\s` или `\p{Zs}`. Только одно но: вариант с `\p` работает только на сервере (server side validation).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь !